Installing pyodbc in windows [local machine]
I am tying to install 'pyodbc' in windows. I have installed the driver from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#download-for-windows and then did a [pip install pyodbc'. But getting the following:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/32/a1/cd1d0d854e3621a13e0364cbe91d56614ae1cebb132a2c2c5755b38b5572/pyodbc-5.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Any help would be highly appreciated  :)
installed pip
installed the ODBC driver

As far as I can tell, the error is that files.pythonhosted.org (the location of the package you're trying to install) is not trusted by pip.
Try running this command.
pip install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools

Basically what it does, is upgrading the pip config file to trust files.pythonhosted.org, which is where the package you are trying to install is located.
If that doesn't work, try disabling any VPNs, proxies or allowing files.pythonhosted.org through your firewall.
